# Is it possible to work in $L^1$ with a non complete measure?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Basically I think that it is implicit when we traditionally build $L^1(X)$ that the measure is complete. BUT WHAT IF it isn’t complete, is it possible? And what properties do we loss (for sure it won’t be complete but maybe more?)

Comment: "It is implicit we traditionally build $L^1(X)$ that the measure is complete". Not sure what makes you think that. Yes, the Lebesgue measure is complete, and this is a good property it has. But it doesn't mean that non complete measure spaces are not interesting. Many product spaces are not complete, in probability theory we usually use non complete spaces (like the Borel measure on $(0,1]$), and so on. Anyway, you can define the $L^p$ spaces on any measure space, and $L^p(X)$ will always be a Banach space.

Comment: This implicit thing that I put there is that when we prove that $L^p$ is complete we assume that the point wise limit is inside $L^p$, and also we assume that the integral of this function is well defined.

Comment: I assure you that the proof of completeness of $L^p$ can be made to work even if the measure is not complete.  If you're not seeing it, perhaps you can post the proof you're looking at, and indicate the place where you think it breaks down?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I will study it a bit more and I will post the proof in case that the problem persist :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $ 
(X, \overline{\mathcal{A}}, \mu’)$ be its completion. Then the spaces $L^p(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ and $L^p (X, \overline{\mathcal{A}}, \mu’)$ are isomorphic, i.e. for all practical purposes they are the same. Roughly speaking this is because the sigma algebras agree modulo null sets. Hence, whether a measure space is complete or not cannot possibly affect the $L^p$ space, since its measure space completion would give the same $L^p$ space.

Comment: But this new $L^p(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is not complete when we build it (we just assume that point wise limit of functions here is inside $L^p(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$, at least that is what we use when we prove the completeness of this space), with this I mean something like $\overline{L^p(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)}=L^p(X,\overline{\mathcal{A}},\mu)$. Maybe there's something I'm missing from when we build $L^p$.

Comment: @DIEGOJAURE: No, this is not true. I agree that you first only get convergence a.e., but you can modify the limit function on a null set such that it becomes measurable w.r.t. the incomplete measure. The $L^p$ space is a Banach space even if the measure is not complete.